# Conditional structure on Picklist in Custom email template

Tags: email, email-template, html

I've been trying to render the value of a picklist field in a conditional statement where if the field is null there should not be anything rendered and is there is a value in the field then it should be rendered in the email template.

I am using a custom email template and working in HTML version here the block of code

```
<div Style="font-family : Roboto;">
 <p style="text-align: left">Une requête vous a été assigné. Voici les détails.</p>
 <div style="Text-Align: left;">
  <p><b>Sujet de la requête</b> : {!Case.Subject}</p>
  <p><b>Raison identifiée :</b> {!Case.Reason} </p>
  <p><b>Description</b> : {!Case.Description}</p>
  <p><b>Requête # :</b> <a Href="{!Case.Link}" Style="color: #009900" >{!Case.CaseNumber} </a></p>

 <p>Vous pouvez visionner la requête en effectuant un clic sur le numéro de requête présent dans ce courriel.</p>

  </div>                                                       
 </div>
```

What I am trying to do is having {!Case.Reason} in a conditional statement but whatever I try, as soon as I put it in the statement no value will be shown. I have looked into multiple forum and post to try to fix this but nothing is working. Here is what I have tried so far

```
{!IF(Case.Reason = "" , "" , Case.Reason) } 
{!IF(TEXT(Case.Reason) = "" , "" , TEXT(Case.Reason)) }
{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Case.Reason) = "" , "" , TEXT(Case.Reason)) }
{!IF(ISPICKVAL(Case.Reason, ""), "" , TEXT(Case.Reason)) }
```

I also tried changing the "" value for Null and  tried ISBLANK(), ISNULL()